# Sum the values in a column except the header

Tags: text-processing, ksh, columns

I have a file as given below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Name_Customer   Item_Purchased  Item_Amount Credit
--------------------------------------------------------------
Tom              H1_P            7657        N/A    
Pras             Track_1         23          N/A
Cha              Brace           9           N/A
Moh              kite37          269         N/A
Prab             Bols            87699       N/A
```

I need to add the values under the column `Item_Amount` by ignoring the header in the file and print the sum as

```
Total Amount collected = 95657
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
awk '{s+=$3}END{print s}' yourfile
```

Comment: @coffeMug can you explain why use this: `s+0`?.

Comment: @Cold don’t remember exactly why that 0 is there! :-P Seems to be unnecessary so removed it!

Comment: @coffeMug probably to ensure awk treated the argument as a number

Answer (score 6):

Pretty trivial using just `awk`. Assuming the example data is in a file, `ex.txt`:

```
$ awk '{total = total + int($3)}END{print "Total Amount collected = "total}' ex.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '{total = total + $3}END{print "Total Amount collected = "total}' ex.txt 
Total Amount collected = 95657
```

#### Details

Using `awk` we collect the values from the 3rd column (`$3`) and accumulate their sub-total in the variable `total`. Once complete, as the last thing to do, `END{..}`, we print the message along with the value of the variable `total`.

Comment: just make one changes `int($3)`

Comment: That little `int($3)` gets things the way I need it.

Answer (score 2):

```
total=0; 
for n in  $( tail -n +4 /tmp/reports.txt | awk '{print $3}') ; 
do 
   total=$( expr $total + $n ); 
done ; 
echo ">>$total"
```

Comment: You can't change the value of a variable inside a loop like that. See my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93108/22222) for a way to make variables accessible outside their loop.s

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` approach is probably the easiest. Here are a few other choices:

Perl:

```
perl -lane '$k+=$F[2];END{print $k}' foo.txt
```

Pure coreutils:

```
t=0; tail -n +4 foo.txt | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -d $'\t' -f 3 | 
 while read i; do let t+=$i; echo $t; done  | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If it can help:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+' your_file|tr '\n' '+'|sed 's/\+$//'|bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

This pipeline should do the work:

```
tail -n +4 the_file | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { printf "Total Amount collected = %d\n", sum }'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{FS=","}{s+=$6}END{print s}' Filename
```

Comment: Can you explain it?

Comment: Welcome to U&L, this hardly add anything to accepted answer and other, besides I don't see the use of FS.

Comment: Given that there are no commas in the sample input, how does this work?